# Counting Number of Swaps for BubbleSort

Tags: java, bubble-sort

the method that I created does not count the number of swaps correctly for the bubble sort algorithm. It does count the number of comparisons. Where did I go wrong with my logic?

```
public static void bubbleSort_Tracker(int[] values) {
    int comps = 0;
    int swaps = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < values.length - 1; j++) {
      for(int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {

        // count the number of comparisons
        comps++;

        // compare neighboring elements
        if(values[i] > values[i+1]) {

          // swap i with i+1
          int temp = values[i];
          values[i] = values[i + 1];
          values[i + 1] = temp;

          // count number of swaps
          swaps++;
        }
      }
    }
    print(values);
    System.out.println("Comparisons: " + comps 
                         + " Swaps: " + swaps);
```

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't count the number of `swaps`?

Comment: Your bubble sort code looks correct.  Have you verified this?

Comment: You should exit outer loop when no swap was occurred in inner loop.

Comment: The output is:                                                                                                  1 4 5 6 10 11 14 15 15 16 18 18 19 23 23 25 27 27 36 37 40 44 47 51 52 53 53 55 56 57 58 59 59 65 67 67 69 70 77 78 82 85 87 87 88 90 91 92 96 97 
Comparisons: 2401 Swaps: 0                                                                             For some reason it is not counting the number of swaps for 50 random integers correctly.